# compiling ldc2 on a centOS 5 system with no root access

Tags: centos, compiling

I git-cloned the latest version of ldc2, but I don't know how to compile it on my centOS 5 machine:

```
git clone --recursive git://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc
cd ldc
git submodule update --init
```

`cmake` doesn't seem to do much. Neither does `cmake Unix Makefiles`

Any ideas? There is no INSTALL file and the README file doesn't mention any installation instructions.

Comment: I'd look for files in the `ldc` directory named `README` and `INSTALL`. They usually explain the particularities of the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README states the following:

> If you have a working C++ build environment, CMake, a current LLVM and
>   libconfig++ (http://hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig.html)
>   available, there should be no big surprises, though.

Do you have the package `cmake` installed? Additionally I'd install the package group "Development Tools".

On Red Hat based distros you can install groups of packages. This facility provides groups of packages that are related to a particular type of task:

- Development
- Educational Software
- Editors

You can see a complete list with this command:

```
$ yum grouplist | less
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Setting up Group Process
Installed Groups:
   Administration Tools
   Arabic Support
   Armenian Support
   Assamese Support
   Authoring and Publishing
   Base
   Bengali Support
   Bhutanese Support
   Chinese Support
   Development Libraries
   Development Tools
   Dial-up Networking Support
   ...
```

To get all the packages typically needed to build software you'll usually need to install compilers + libraries. These can be had by using this command:

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Incidentally you can see what packages are in a group using this command:

```
$ yum groupinfo "Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Setting up Group Process

Group: Development Tools
 Description: These tools include core development tools such as automake, gcc, perl, python, and debuggers.
 Mandatory Packages:
   autoconf
   automake
   binutils
   bison
   flex
   gcc
   gcc-c++
   ...
```

Cmake is part of this group:

```
$ yum groupinfo "Development Tools"|grep cmake
   cmake
```